# Should networks get wider as they get deeper or narrower?

Tags: neural-networks, predictive-models

In a network with multiple hidden layers, should the layers start with fewer neurons and gain more neurons before the output layer?  Should they start with more neurons in the first few layers and gradually get smaller, or should they have an equal number of neurons in each layer?

Comment: Different networks do different things to solve different problems. It’s not unusual to project up, then down (e.g., transformers).

Comment: Yes, I don't think there's a one-size-fits-all answer. You may need to tune the layer sizes as a hyperparameter (i.e., search over cross product of layer sizes). If this is infeasible due to the number of layers, perhaps there's a similar architecture for your task you can use as a starting point.

Comment: I have just 6 layers so it should be very feasible. Thank you.